# Does a very low loss and low accuracy indicate overfitting?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm training a CNN-LSTM concat model and after 20 epochs I got an accuracy of 69% and a loss of 0.04?

I know that the combination of very high training accuracy and relatively low validation accuracy indicates overfitting but I was wondering if a low accuracy and a very low loss would also indicate overfitting.

Overall, the accuracy increased linearly and the loss decreased exponentially.

Comment: That depends on which loss and what is the task, you should add those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more details regarding task, loss and so on would be appreciated.

For the training set the loss should have a inverse relationship with the metric e.g. accuracy. If the loss goes down the accuracy should go up. If this is not the case you might want to have a look at the loss function and metric.

So a very low loss and very low accuracy on the same dataset would indicate for me, that something is wrong with the model I want to train and that the model is not learning to solve the task I want it to solve.